# How do you view the status of your svn-git repo?

Tags: git-svn

I understand how to initialize a git-svn repo, create a branch, do some work, merge branch, then use `git svn rebase` and `git svn dcommit` to push back to the svn repo. But between these two commands, how can you get a status of what is different between the two repos? Something like a `git status` that tells you that you have x number of files that have been changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a diff between your branch and upstream.

```
git diff --stat git-svn/master..master
```

Obviously, you'll have to change the branch names to whatever's applicable for your setup.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way I know is to run 'git svn dcommit -n' (or git svn dcommit --dry-run) which will usually give you output like this:

```
$git svn dcommit --dry-run
Committing to http://yourserver.com/trunk ...
diff-tree bc923cb54847fa340d094c3da1ebd66b8fb0e63e~1 bc923cb54847fa340d094c3da1ebd66b8fb0e63e
diff-tree a05c8be4af7f82dc4de5b4778e2b58203c75eebd~1 a05c8be4af7f82dc4de5b4778e2b58203c75eebd
```

And then you can 'git show bc923cb54847fa340d094c3da1ebd66b8fb0e63e' to view that diff.